# Move all artifacts to S3 root

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-codebuild

I'm using CodeBuild to make builds from repository (Angular app). My artifacts are in dist/appName folder. Here's part of my buildspec.yml:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
  discard-paths: yes
  base-directory: dist
```

No matter how I configure artifacts section the artifacts are copied to appName folder in S3 bucket.
How can I put artifacts in S3 root?

Comment: `artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  discard-paths: yes
  base-directory: 'dist*'` This may work for you.

Comment: for more information about buildspec you can follow this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html

Comment: Thanks Sunil, it turned out I had pathName in codebuild output... all I had to do was to change it to /. Nothing to do with buildspec